# Angular nested component routing

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-router

I have a navbar component which has one routerLink

```
 <p>
  <a routerLink="/user">User</a>
</p>
```

and a nested component under UserComponent to which I am passing value

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-user',
  template: `
    <input #box (keyup.enter)="onEnter(box.value)">
    <div *ngIf="box.size > 0">
      <app-order [value]="value"></app-order>
    </div>`

})
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {

  value = '';

  onEnter(value: string) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

OrderComponent

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-order',
  template:`{{id}}`
})
export class OrderComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() id:String;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Now when I enter user link I get my view with link and my passed value. When I click the link again, I get the same page with value. How can I change this behavior so that when I click on the route button again I get the input without the passed value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come across the same problem when trying to refresh a page when clicking on its associated button on the navbar.

Angular states that a navigation on the same URL has no effect since the state of the application is represented by its current URL.

There is a workaround for this : [onSameUrlNavigation](https://angular.io/api/router/ExtraOptions)

Unfortunately, this option only allows the guards and resolvers to run again when navigating to the same URL, so if you activate it you'll notice...nothing at all!

So I created my own workaround with this class:

```
/**
 * Abstract class that allows derived components to get refreshed automatically on route change.
 * The actual use case is : a page gets refreshed by navigating on the same URL and we want the rendered components to refresh
 */
export abstract class AutoRefreshingComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  public routerEventsSubscription: Subscription;
  protected router: Router;

  constructor() { 
    this.router = AppInjector.get(Router);
  }

  /**
   * Initialization behavior. Note that derived classes must not implement OnInit.
   * Use initialize() on derived classes instead.
   */
  ngOnInit() {
    this.initialize();
    this.routerEventsSubscription = this.router.events.filter(x => x instanceof NavigationEnd).subscribe(res => {
      this.initialize();
    });
  }

  /**
   * Destruction behavior. Note that derived classes must not implement OnDestroy.
   * Use destroy() on derived classes instead.
   */
  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.routerEventsSubscription.unsubscribe();
    this.destroy();
  }

  /**
   * Function that allows derived components to define an initialization behavior
   */
  abstract initialize(): void;

  /**
   * Function that allows derived components to define a destruction behavior
   */
  abstract destroy(): void;

}
```

AppInjector refers to this:

```
import {Injector} from '@angular/core';

/**
 * Allows for retrieving singletons using `AppInjector.get(MyService)` (whereas
 * `ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate(MyService)` would create a new instance
 * of the service).
 */
export let AppInjector: Injector;

/**
 * Helper to access the exported {@link AppInjector}, needed as ES6 modules export
 * immutable bindings; see http://2ality.com/2015/07/es6-module-exports.html
 */
export function setAppInjector(injector: Injector) {
    if (AppInjector) {
        // Should not happen
        console.error('Programming error: AppInjector was already set');
    }
    else {
        AppInjector = injector;
    }
}
```

And in your AppModule:

```
import { setAppInjector } from './app.injector';

// ...

export class AppModule {
  constructor(private injector: Injector) {
    setAppInjector(injector);
  }
}
```

Then make all of your needed component extend `AutoRefreshingComponent`.

In your case:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-user',
  template: `
    <input #box (keyup.enter)="onEnter(box.value)">
    <div *ngIf="box.size > 0">
      <app-order [value]="value"></app-order>
    </div>`

})
export class UserComponent extends AutoRefreshingComponent {

  value = '';

  onEnter(value: string) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  constructor() {
  }

  initialize() {
     // Reset your box value
  }

  destroy() {
  }

}
```

This may be overkill for what you want to achieve, but it will be useful every time you want to refresh a component on same URL navigation.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work :(  OnSameUrlNavigation workaround also seems like lots of code to write.

Comment: I provided full reusable code, for your purpose you could copy only the `this.router.events.filter(x => x instanceof NavigationEnd).subscribe(res => {/** Your code **/ });` part. Dont forget `onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload'` in your `RouterModule` configuration

Comment: I have added onSameUrlNavigation parameter and it works.

Comment: @bkubiak glad it helped! feel free to accept the answer